# Halt reading of CSS

Tags: css

I'm writing an MVC with the aid of Materialize CSS, however when it comes to forms there are times where I require my own form style (not always).

Anyway, my question is (I think I read somewhere before that it can be done) - How do I halt/stop certain HTML/DOM from being influenced by a stylesheet that's already influencing the document the HTML/DOM will be contained in?

For example:

```
    <link rel="styl...
</head>
<body>
    <!-- stop reading css for now, I will use inline styling temporarily. -->
    <form>
         <input ty...
    </form>
</body>
```

My question derives from how the materialize influences form elements directly, so `<input type="text"/>` is influenced by materialize CSS.

Comment: Well, you seem new to HTML/CSS. Can't you just `class="someClass"` and it won't read it as Materialize? Erhh. Or look in the Materialize CSS for where it styles form attributes, and change it? I'm assuming the Materialize uses CSS like this: `input[type=text]` if you're having problems with it formatting your forms that aren't calling classes.

Not sure how you'd halt CSS or if it's even possible so not posted as answer.

Comment: Hi @Cherryade, materialize directly influences the base form elements, input, textarea, label - I know I can just remove this from the materialize CSS file but I've already implemented it in places and don't wanna have to do that - so adding a `class="someClass"` would still result in this materialize influence unless I completely over-wrote every element for that class, surely there must be a more effective way.

Comment: Going to take some elbow grease unfortunately.

You're going to have to change the `input[type=text]` etc. from your Materialize and then add a separate class for them styles, and call them everywhere you want Materialize to actually style your forms. Alternatively you can do a new `input[type=text]` and after each line in that class just shove a `!important` in there, meaning if there's a border on it and you don't want one, you'll have to specify you don't want one and put `!important` on the end.

Comment: @Cherryade, I know that's an option - but if I wanted that answer I wouldn't have asked the question I did ^^. Thanks anyway.

Comment: my answer may not 'halt' css but it is a solution to your problems.

Comment: Yeah but so is creating an entirely new website and viewing it through an iframe @Cherryade.

Comment: Wouldnt the easiest way be to wrap Materialize in a class? Just use `LESS` or `SASS` to wrap the entire file in a class like `.materialise` and then call that class on where you want to apply materialise.

Comment: @somethinghere I didn't really wanna use LESS/SASS for this project, but I may look into it if there are no other alternatives. It's a bit hit and miss with materialize, some styles do have the `ma` prefix.

Comment: @JackHardcastle the only reason I suggest `LESS` or `SASS` is to quickly output a standard css file with a wrapping class (just rename the materialise file `.scss` and then go `.materialise { @import "materialise"; }` - then just use the outputted file. Its a time-saver and you only have to do it once.

Comment: @somethinghere this may affect the materialize javascript, any thoughts on that?/solutions?

Comment: I think it shouldn't make a difference as I assume the JS is written to allow for nesting anyhow, so this would only apply the CSS if the class it there (so it means the JS might add classes to inputs but that would make no visual difference since the classes are only defined to things wrapped inside your `materialise` class. Actually, Im pretty sure it wont directly affect any JS.

Answer (score 0):

Just add, and then call the following class on everything you want to reset:

To be annoying: Might have to add !important on the end :)

```
.defaultClass {
    animation : none;
    animation-delay : 0;
    animation-direction : normal;
    animation-duration : 0;
    animation-fill-mode : none;
    animation-iteration-count : 1;
    animation-name : none;
    animation-play-state : running;
    animation-timing-function : ease;
    backface-visibility : visible;
    background : 0;
    background-attachment : scroll;
    background-clip : border-box;
    background-color : transparent;
    background-image : none;
    background-origin : padding-box;
    background-position : 0 0;
    background-position-x : 0;
    background-position-y : 0;
    background-repeat : repeat;
    background-size : auto auto;
    border : 0;
    border-style : none;
    border-width : medium;
    border-color : inherit;
    border-bottom : 0;
    border-bottom-color : inherit;
    border-bottom-left-radius : 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius : 0;
    border-bottom-style : none;
    border-bottom-width : medium;
    border-collapse : separate;
    border-image : none;
    border-left : 0;
    border-left-color : inherit;
    border-left-style : none;
    border-left-width : medium;
    border-radius : 0;
    border-right : 0;
    border-right-color : inherit;
    border-right-style : none;
    border-right-width : medium;
    border-spacing : 0;
    border-top : 0;
    border-top-color : inherit;
    border-top-left-radius : 0;
    border-top-right-radius : 0;
    border-top-style : none;
    border-top-width : medium;
    bottom : auto;
    box-shadow : none;
    box-sizing : content-box;
    caption-side : top;
    clear : none;
    clip : auto;
    color : inherit;
    columns : auto;
    column-count : auto;
    column-fill : balance;
    column-gap : normal;
    column-rule : medium none currentColor;
    column-rule-color : currentColor;
    column-rule-style : none;
    column-rule-width : none;
    column-span : 1;
    column-width : auto;
    content : normal;
    counter-increment : none;
    counter-reset : none;
    cursor : auto;
    direction : ltr;
    display : inline;
    empty-cells : show;
    float : none;
    font : normal;
    font-family : inherit;
    font-size : medium;
    font-style : normal;
    font-variant : normal;
    font-weight : normal;
    height : auto;
    hyphens : none;
    left : auto;
    letter-spacing : normal;
    line-height : normal;
    list-style : none;
    list-style-image : none;
    list-style-position : outside;
    list-style-type : disc;
    margin : 0;
    margin-bottom : 0;
    margin-left : 0;
    margin-right : 0;
    margin-top : 0;
    max-height : none;
    max-width : none;
    min-height : 0;
    min-width : 0;
    opacity : 1;
    orphans : 0;
    outline : 0;
    outline-color : invert;
    outline-style : none;
    outline-width : medium;
    overflow : visible;
    overflow-x : visible;
    overflow-y : visible;
    padding : 0;
    padding-bottom : 0;
    padding-left : 0;
    padding-right : 0;
    padding-top : 0;
    page-break-after : auto;
    page-break-before : auto;
    page-break-inside : auto;
    perspective : none;
    perspective-origin : 50% 50%;
    position : static;
    /* May need to alter quotes for different locales (e.g fr) */
    quotes : '\201C' '\201D' '\2018' '\2019';
    right : auto;
    tab-size : 8;
    table-layout : auto;
    text-align : inherit;
    text-align-last : auto;
    text-decoration : none;
    text-decoration-color : inherit;
    text-decoration-line : none;
    text-decoration-style : solid;
    text-indent : 0;
    text-shadow : none;
    text-transform : none;
    top : auto;
    transform : none;
    transform-style : flat;
    transition : none;
    transition-delay : 0s;
    transition-duration : 0s;
    transition-property : none;
    transition-timing-function : ease;
    unicode-bidi : normal;
    vertical-align : baseline;
    visibility : visible;
    white-space : normal;
    widows : 0;
    width : auto;
    word-spacing : normal;
    z-index : auto;
}
```